# Meaning of "love will make us"?

Tags: quotations

> *"Come sleep with me. We won't make love. Love will make us." - Julio Cortazar*

What does the part of **"love will make us"** mean?

Comment: It's poetic.  What do you think it means?

Comment: It sounds like the meaning of this is ambiguous and up for interpretation

Comment: @mcraen it is and this question will probably be closed as a result.  But I think christie can ask over at [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/) if it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just "playing with words" - the intended meaning (if any) is a matter of interpretation. @Andrew: It would still be POB on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is there an SE site dedicated to literary interpretation?

Comment: @Andrew: I doubt TPTB would endorse such a site on SO, since almost *by definition* there couldn't normally be a "single, definitively correct" answer. There might be a bit of wiggle room on writers.SE, but I doubt it would pass muster even there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a play on the phrase "make love", which means to have sexual intercourse.

In this context Julio is saying that the sex will make both himself and his partner(s) who they are (or rather, who they will be, since the event is in the future). This is in direct contrast to the usual usage of "make love", which describes an activity which is distinct from the participants.

It's also worth noting that "make love" has emotional connotations beyond "sexual intercourse", and is a gentler, more polite expression.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail about what you mean by "**make** both himself and his partner(s)?"  i.e. what is the *figurative* and *poetic* use of "make" in this context?